# How can I make width property start from right to left instead of left to right

Tags: html, css

I want `::before` animation start right to left when `width: 100%;` and when you hover it the animation go from left to right (going back) `width: 0;` is there a way to do this with css?

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: ease-in-out 3s;
}

span::before , span::after{
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: ease-in-out 3s;

 
}
span::before {
    left: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    right: 0;
    top: 2px;
    transition: ease-in-out 3s;
}
span:hover::after, span:hover::before{
  width: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out 3s;
}

.kotak:hover {
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      </head>
      
      <body>
        
        <Span>PLACEHOLDER</Span>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify your logic like below. Switch between `left` and `right` to control the position

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(red 0 0) top    right,
   linear-gradient(red 0 0) bottom left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 5px;
  transition: ease-in-out 1s,background-position 0s 1s;
  /* or simply transition: ease-in-out 1s */
}

span:hover{
  background-size:0% 5px;
  background-position: /* remove this to keep the same position */
   top    left,
   bottom right
}
```

```html
<span>PLACEHOLDER</span>
```

Comment: linear-gradient(red 0 0) what is the 0 stands for the first one i assume is color stop and what is the latter stand for?

Comment: @Lopzx both are color stops. This a kind of hacky expression to make it shorter. it means that I place one color at both 0 and 0 but the browser will later change the last 0 to 100% ;) so it's like `linear-gradient(red 0 100%)` which is also `linear-gradient(red 0,red 100%)`

Answer (score 0):

after some testing i finally found answer to my question
i added comments to the code snippet

```css
/* Use Parent set to relative to contain absolute */
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom : 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

/* Set Position to Absolute so we can use top,right,bottom,left */
.box::before,
.box::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 3s;
}

/* Set to right so the ::before start from right side to the left */
.box::before {
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;

}

.box:hover::after,
.box:hover::before {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      </head>
      
      <body>
        
        <div class="box">PLACE HOLDERDERER</div>




       
     </body>
</html>
```